# Cron job to execute a Flask/Python function inside a docker container?

Tags: python, docker, flask, cron

I would like to use a cron job outside a docker container to execute a Python/Flask function inside a docker container.

Is it possible to do so?

Just doing a `docker exec` doesn't do so, I believe Flask might have some limitations with allowing access to functions.

Or is there a better alternative?

Here is a sample code in `main.py`
I would like the cron job to execute `getThisFunction()` in main.py that is running in a docker container

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello():
        return "Hello World!"

@routes.route('/getThisFunction', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def getThisFunction():
    return "foobar"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I would like a cron job like below (not exactly similar):

`26 08 * * * docker exec c78ddbed4ad9 {some stuff to execute getThisFunction() in main.py}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can expose the flask url to the internal network like, where your docker flask address is `http://10.0.0.2/myflaskapp`

Now you can call in cronjob a call to this http page using `curl`.